# MapReduce: Given a file of numbers, output the amount of distinct / unique numbers

Tags: hadoop, count, mapreduce, distinct

If the Input file is: `1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6`, then the output of MapReduce should be **6** (i.e. the size of the set of unique integers `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`).

I need help with implementing the above. I know that we can filter out duplicates by emitting each number vs. a null value in `map()`, and then similarly output the key vs. a null value in `reduce()` to a resultant file / console.

But if I directly need to get the number of distinct numbers, how would I go about with this?

My current implementation is to build a Set, pass it as the output of the Mapper, and in the Reducer, combine all Sets passed to it, and return the count of that resultant Set. Do note that this is more of a design question than a library-specific (say, Hadoop) implementation question.

Comment: Sounds great. Now, where's the code? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service

Comment: Added a bit more details on what I know and what I have been able to understand so far.

Comment: Why exactly do you need map reduce for this? Specifically *reduce*? It's a map only operation to filter duplicates and write the amount of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a mapper to build a Hashset. Make the output of IntWritable and NullWritable.

Add all the input values to the Set.

Write out the size of the Hashset.

Set number of Reduce Tasks to 0, since it's not needed.

---

If you must use a Reducer, output (null, value) from the mapper.

Do the same as above.

---

Alternative (simpler) methods exist if you can use Hive, Pig, or Spark